# Magento1.9 dispatch/shipping confirmation email issue

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, order-email

Magento is not sending shipping/dispatch confirmation email but is sending 
other (create/update/complete) emails.
Not sure why. Checked "order.php" but I couldn't find any obvious reason there.

Where to look or what to change in settings to make it work and to force Magento to send emails on certain order status ?

No errors in logs (system.log and exceptions.log).

What is triggering email sending order state change or order status change ?